# Flask form: When form validation fails with an error then FileField does not show already attached file information

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

When a form is submitted and validation fails with an error in a field information entered by the user is retained but it does not show `FileField` attachment info.

I am trying to upload a file to the server on selecting a file, even before the form has been submitted.

Can anyone suggest me a way to retain `fileField` information which has already been attached by the user? How can I at least populate the file name if not file data on the fileField (file content I can upload on change fileField through AJAX)

```
class UploadFileForm(FlaskForm):
  name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
  docFile = FileField('File(s) Upload', render_kw={'multiple': True}, )
  author = StringField('Author', validators=[DataRequired("Select Document Author")], )
  submit = SubmitField('Save')
```